# NextJS 500 internal server error on deployed website but the other pages works works well

Tags: next.js

I made another deployment for a deployed production app using Microsoft Azure Static Web App. Now, the index page is 500 internal server error while other pages still works well.

Context: If I visit <deployed_url>/login, the 500 Internal Server Error shows but if I go to <deployed_url>/register, the website works as expected even when navigating to login page from the register page.